# matplotlib pyplot not accurately representing time along x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a JSON array of around 3000 records each spaced 1 minute apart which I want to plot on a timeseries graph using `matplotlib`. However I cannot get the data to display properly on a chart with the date and times along the x axis.

The records are formatted as follows:

```
{
    "datetime": "10-07-2017  21:57:37", 
    "deviceid": "PiJCLabDoor", 
    "dht11": 24.0, 
    "dht22": null, 
    "id": 39751, 
    "motion": 0.0, 
    "pressure": null, 
    "uv": 0.04, 
    "voc": 126.0
  }
```

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_json('PiJCLabDoor.json', convert_dates=['datetime'])
dataframe = DataFrame(data)

for i in range(0, dataframe.shape[0] -1):

    if (dataframe.loc[i, 'dht11'] - dataframe.loc[i+1, 'dht11']) > 3 :
    dataframe.loc[i+1, 'dht11'] = dataframe.loc[i,'dht11']
```

These lines of code yield the following chart:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,7)
plt.plot(dataframe['datetime'], dataframe['dht11'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

And these lines of code yield the following chart:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20,6)
plt.plot(dataframe['dht11'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The second chart is what the data should look like however the first chart has dates on the x axis.

How do I get the date and time to appear on the x axis of the second chart?
Thanks

Comment: Well, it could be accurately representing your data, `'dht11'` can be nice and steady for dates between 2017-06-14 and 2017-09-04. Notice the second plot shows the code with uniform x distribution.

Comment: To put the above in other words, it does not make sense to show dates on the second graph, because that would mean that the axes scale becomes unsteady and non-linear. The first chart is an accurate representation of the data in units of time, so this is the one that should be used.

Comment: Hi Vinicius, thanks for you reply. The second is the accurate representation as each record is one minute apart so they are definitely spaced linearly. I have plotted the data in d3.js and it works fine (like the second graph). 

Also the data is for temperatures and examining the dataset reveals that the data distribution is nothing like graph 1. i.e the temperature does not stay stable for 24 hours, then spike and dip for 2 hours and then stay stable again.

Comment: Looking at this again I'm sure that it is interpreting the day as the month and as there are only 2 days of data it is filling the rest with the two static lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, remember to convert datetime to Pandas datetime (pd.to_datetime())
To make the dates appear on second graph set datetime column as index, something like:

```
plt.plot(dataframe.set_index('datetime')['dht11'])
```

EDIT:

So if i get it right you have something like this:

[image]

There is a 1 week gap between dates, and you want to have them one next to another so:

```
x = np.arange(len(a['date']))

plt.plot(x, a['value'])
plt.xticks(x, a['date'], rotation=45)
```

First I do something like in your first graph, then I change the name of xlabels to have the same as dates. Result looks like that:

[image]

But you might find that the xticks appears too often, then just change one line there, like this:

```
plt.xticks(x[::3], a['date'][::3], rotation=45)
```

So now only every third date will appear on the graph.

EDIT 2:

If you want to set only X main dates on your x-axis use this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
plt.plot(x, a['value'])
plt.xticks(x, a['date'], rotation=45)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(LinearLocator(numticks=5))
```

In numticks you specify how many ticks should appear

Comment: Thanks, that creates the first chart however it is still interpreting the month as the date and vice versa. I've tried all manner of things with pd.to_datetime() but cannot get it to work.

Comment: So you want to remove straight line between the unsteady data, make the three groups closer to each other and keep the dates?

Comment: Edited: sorry I misread your answer. let me just change my code!

Comment: Thank you so much Kacper! This is very almost exactly what I want, my only problem now is that the xticks are printed on top of each other even when I limit them to say one every 500 dates

Sorry for being such a needy n00b! Thanks again

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! You are a true master!